# Prove that $X_{\tau}$ is a random variable.

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, measurable-functions

Let ${Y_{n}, n \geq 0}$ be real-valued random variables on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ that satisfy
$\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} X_{n}(\omega) = \infty$
for every $\omega \in \Omega$, and let $B < \infty$ be a real number. Prove that the integer-valued
quantity
$$τ (ω) := \inf\left\{n ≥ 0 : X_{n}(\omega)\geq B\right\}$$
is a random variable. Also, prove that $X_{\tau}$ is a random variable.

My attempt so far,

I have been able to prove that $\tau(\omega)$ is a random variable. If some $k \notin \mathbb{Z^{+}}$, then $\tau^{-1}(\{k\}) = \phi$. We know that $\phi$ has a pre-image in $\mathcal{F}$.$$\tau_{\omega} = k \implies X_{k}(\omega) \geq B \cap X_{i}(\omega) < B$$ for all $i<k$. Since, the $\{X\}'s$ are random variables, $A_{k} \cap (\cap_{i=1}^{k-1}A_{i})$ where, $A_{k} = X_{k}^{-1}([B,\infty)) , X_{k}^{-1} = ((-\infty,B)).$

I am not so sure about how to proceed for proving that $X_{\tau}$ is a random variable.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Write $$X_{\tau} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} X_n 1_{\{\tau=n\}}$$

1. What do you know about the measurability of $X_n$ and $1_{\{\tau=n\}}$?
2. What do you know about measurability of products, sums and limits of measurable functions?

Comment: We know $X_{n}$ are measurable because they are random variables. Since, $\tau$ is measurable, the indicator function of that set is measurable. I am not sure about the products, sums, and limits though.

Comment: @aa777 It's a good start. If you nothing about products etc, then you should definitely look this up ... it's really one of the crucial tools to prove measurability. What happens if you add/multiply two measurable functions? Do you get something measurable? If $Y_n$ are measurable functions which converge pointwise, then is the limit $\lim_n Y_n$ measurable? Give it a go!

Comment: Thank you so much @saz. I will definitely look into it.

Comment: @aa777 You are welcome. Feel free to contact me if you get stuck.